# Adding from 2 databases to a listView row

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Can I add data 2 from different databases into each row of a ListView in Android?

I have a vendor app and I want to add data from one standard items list table and one daily table to the list view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you won't be able to use the `CursorAdapter`s implementation easily. I would put all data you need inside an array, and then you can write your own `BaseAdapter` or use an implementation of `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to checkout Commonswares [CWAC-MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) maybe it is of use for your problem. It is meant to provide you an easy way of handling multiple data sources and views for display in one `ListView`.